# How to get all city pages from Wikipedia by using LINQ-to-Wiki?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, wikipedia-api

I have used LINQ-to-Wiki to get pages from Wikipedia to my ASP.NET MVC webapplication.I have used the below query to get Pages having title like "India".

```
var wikipedia = new Wiki("Example");
var data = wikipedia.Query.allpages()
        .Where(i => i.prefix == "India")
        .ToList();
```

But it gives all pages related to "India" not only Places/Cities.How to get only Places/Cities from this query?Or how to search a place by 'categorymembers' property.Can anyone please help?

Comment: is this Linq-to-wikipedia (https://linqtowikipedia.codeplex.com/) or LinqtoWiki (https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToWiki)?

Comment: It is LinqtoWiki(nuget.org/packages/LinqToWiki).

Comment: Wikipedia is an encyclopedy, not a database. Please consider using Wikidata instead, that'll provide you Wikipedia sitelinks that you can filter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394863/how-do-you-filter-wikivoyage-api-results-by-city too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this other SO answer: [Wikipedia API - is there a general 'music' category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583879/wikipedia-api-is-there-a-general-music-category).

Wikipedia's OpenSearch implementation does not support categories in the search text.